# In my program i want to detect Activities (walking,running) or location of user When Application is closed(not in Background).is it possible in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-motion, motion-detection

In my program i want to detect Activities (walking,running) or location  of user When Application is closed.is it possible ?

Description:-

i am using SOMOtionDetector Class for detecting users activity.When my app is closed(not in background) is there any way to calling those functions??

thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the application? I work with a research group that does work on this but we use android specifically for the reason that it is better at handling background tasks and our app does not need to be running to sense motion and other data. We use MIT's funf framework though it does have a few shortcomings

Comment: @inquisitiveIdiot it's fine.but in ios is there any way to calling function of ViewController when application is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can help you [LINK to background supported services](http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios)

Comment: i want when it is close.not in background.

Answer (score -1):

Since you mentioned getting location of User, I guess you may want to study usage of CLLocationManager and geofence,which will wake up your application (even not in background) when user location changes.